# Number of files does not match inodes

Tags: rhel, disk-usage, inode

I notice that the number of used inodes on the OCFS2 partition is around 28 million. I moved a folder that contained 518K files and the number became 22 million.

The following script finds the number of files, it was around 65,000 and number of folders was 40.

My question, where are the number 22 million is coming from ? is that normal ?

```
[root@bopapp1 ~]# cat /etc/issue
Oracle Linux Server release 6.5
Kernel \r on an \m

[root@bopapp1 ~]# uname -a
Linux bopapp1 3.8.13-16.2.1.el6uek.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 7 17:01:44 PST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@bopapp1 ~]# df -i
Filesystem                        Inodes    IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_testapp2-lv_root  3276800   765283  2511517   24% /
tmpfs                            3089556        3  3089553    1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                         128016       55   127961    1% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_testapp2-lv_home  4882432     9662  4872770    1% /home
/dev/dm-4                       39321087 22543323 16777764   58% /u
/dev/dm-5                       26214055  8319457 17894598   32% /usr/oracle

[root@bopapp1 ~]# cd /u

[root@bopapp1 u]# for i in `find . -type d `; do echo `ls -a $i 2> /dev/null | wc -l` $i; done | sort -n | awk '{sum+=$1} END{print "sum=",sum}'
sum= 62950
```

Comment: You're counting directory entries, not files. For instance, you're counting hardlinks (including the `.` and `..` entries) several times. You can't use use command substitution like that, that's the split+glob operator (so you'll fail to list the directories that have blanks or possibly globs in their path).

Comment: ok, I understand that,  but is possible that the hard links will use the rest of 22 million inodes ?

Comment: counting the hard links several times would increase the count. Here the problem is more likely the one you're hiding with your `2> /dev/null` of improperly using the split+glob operator.

Comment: There are also filesystems that dynamically adjust the number of inodes.

Answer (score 2):

I just realised we were talking of an OCFS2 cluster file system here and not a regular on disk local file system. This section applies to OCFS2 specifically. See below for normal file systems.

If I create a new blank 1GiB OCFS2 file system and mount it, I see a used inode count of 36378.

After creating 100 empty files, I don't see this number increasing.

After creating 10000 files, I see it going up to 72730.

If I delete all those files, the number doesn't go down, but if I unmount the FS and mount it back, I see it changing to 45634.

So, though I can't tell you why as I'm not familiar with this file system, it seems the `IUsed` count returned by `df` does not match the number of i-nodes, or that on that file system, i-nodes are not solely used for files or that the system doesn't track its number of used or free i-nodes other than with very gross granularity.

If you run `o2info --freeinode` from ocfs2-tools 1.8.2 or above, you can get a number that is closer to expected:

```
$ du -ax ///mnt/1 | grep -c ///
102
$ df -i /mnt/1
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/loop0     262144 45634 216510   18% /mnt/1
$ o2info --freeinode /mnt/1
Slot            Space           Free
  0             10240          10129
  1                 0              0
Total           10240          10129
$ echo $((10240-10129))
111

$ touch /mnt/1/a{1..100}
$ o2info --freeinode /mnt/1
Slot            Space           Free
  0             10240          10029
  1                 0              0
Total           10240          10029
$ o2info --freeinode /mnt/1 | awk 'END{print $2-$3}'
211

$ touch /mnt/1/b{1..20000}
$ o2info --freeinode /mnt/1
Slot            Space           Free
  0             20480            259
  1                 0              0
Total           20480            259
$ o2info --freeinode /mnt/1 | awk 'END{print $2-$3}'
20221
```

---

Now, for conventional file systems...

To get a match for the inode count by crawling directory entries, you'd need to keep a track of which files you've seen based on inode numbers.

```
find /u -xdev -printf '%i\n' | sort -u | wc -l
```

`du` (at least the GNU implementation) will also skip multiple instances of a same file (hard links), so you can use:

```
 du -xa ///u | grep -c ///
```

which should give you the same result as the `find` one.

I'd expect the result to be slightly less than the `df -i` count as a few file systems (including `ext4`) have a few special inodes that are not linked to any directory for internal use.

It will also fail to count files that have been deleted but are still open by some process (see `lsof +aL1 /u` for the list) and those that are masked by another file system  mounted within (not the case in your example).

Using command substitution (`` `...` ``) like you do is wrong. That's invoking the split+glob operator which by default splits on blanks and performs globbing on the resulting words. So that can only give you a meaningful result if none of the file names contain space, tab, newline, `*`,`?`, or `[` characters.

`ls -a` includes the `.` and `..` entries which you don't want to count as they are hard links for some inodes you've already counted (except for the `.` entry in `/u` itself). And similarly, you're going to count other hard links several times.

Answer (score 0):

You will never be able to match these numbers as there are open but deleted files that are usinf inodes but that are unvisible for users that traverse the filesystem.

There are also hidden inodes (e.g. used by ACL definitions and extended attribute files) that cannot be seen with the `find` command.

On the other side, you would need to prevent to count hard linked times multiple times. This could be achieved via:

`find /u -xdev -ls | sort -n -u +0 | wc -l`

but note that this will usually count too few files (see above).

Comment: What do you mean by _ACL definitions_ and _extended attribute files_? If you mean the POSIX-draft-type ACLs or extended attributes _of_ files, then on Linux (ext4 and xfs at least, btrfs being not inode-based), they are not stored on a separate inode (and I can't see why any FS would use inodes to store them).

Comment: There is nothing that could be called POSIX draft ACLs as the related proposal was withdrawn in 1997 already. But independent from the ACL type, ACLs are usually stored in shadow inodes in order to allow arbitrary sizes. BTW:  What Linux calls "extended attributes" was withdrawn in 1997 as it was part of that withdrawn proposal. The current standard for ACLs and extended attribute files  is part of the NFSv4 standard.

Comment: Note that the `sort -n -u +0` syntax is long obsolete and deprecated and all the `sort` implementations commonly found on modern Linux-based systems like the OP's will not recognise it (SUSv3 even required that command to sort the file called `+0` there, SUSv4 lifted it). The `+0` is superfluous anyway since you're using `-n` (and without it, that would have had to be `+0 -1` or its modern equivalent `-k 1,1`). Note that your `find|sort|wc` command assumes file names don't contain newline characters.

Comment: it's beside the point. The question is about Oracle Linux. Those NFSv4 ACLs on Linux are only supported via an unofficial patch which as far as I know only the OpenSuse distribution applies. On  Linux "native" file systems, extended attributes are *not* stored in separate inodes, even in XFS which is the only one I know that doesn't have a limit on the number and size of them.

Comment: (just noticed we're talking OCFS2 here, and not native on disk FS, I can't say whether my comments apply there as I've not tested it there)

Comment: OK, just created an OCFS2 FS. Blank, the Iused is 36378 and creating files doesn't seem to increase that count. Only after I create 10000 files do I see that increase to 72730 and removing those files doesn't make that number got down again.

Comment: The find command I mentioned works on every genetic UNIX system, while your proposal is based on a non-portable GNUism. Not supporting +n looks unfriendly to me in special when I see the bloated interface of a typical GNU tool.

Comment: Your command doesn't work on the OP's system (and most of the systems users of this site use) or on some systems (including UNIX genetic ones like Solaris 10) where there are filenames or symlink targets with newline characters. Mine works on the OP's system regardless of the names of the files.

Comment: Sorry `s/Oracle Linux/RHEL/` above, though the rest still applies.

Comment: Note that GNU sort supports `sort +0` on systems where _POSIX2_VERSION is strictly less than 200112. If you have a script that was written for such an old standard and uses +0, you can make it work with GNU `sort` by setting the environment variable _POSIX2_VERSION to something like 199209. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Standards-conformance.html) for details.